# What is the opposite of a silent letter?

Tags: terminology

What is the opposite of a silent letter?

For example, let's take the word *vehicle*, which is typically pronounced one of two ways:

- [ˈvi·ɪ·kəl] -- the letter h is silent.
- [ˈvi·hɪ·kəl] -- the letter is not silent

What would linguists call it when not silent, “sounded”?

Comment: A noisy letter? "Silent letter" isn't a linguistic concept, so there is no opposite. They have many uses, for example the "e" in *cache* simply is there in spelling, whereas in "vehicle" there is an an actual /h/ sound which can be deleted when the stress is in the right position.

Comment: Since a letter being pronounced is rather the default (maybe not as strongly in English, but still quite generally), I don't think there's a special term for it; the need of an explicit terminology is only for the special occasion where it is *not* pronounced. But do call it "sounded" of you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In linguistics you can't really talk about "silent letters". Orthography and phonetics follow separate evolutionary paths in most languages, and orthographic spellings rarely have one-to-one correspondences with phonetic sounds.

***tl;dr:* The closest term that comes to mind would be "articulated".**

Usually in phonology if you're talking about sounds not being produced, there's some phonological process involved in not producing them, and so the term used to describe them is usually a variation of the name of the process that causes them not to be articulated. E.g. in "vehicle" the /h/ is the result of [elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision), so you could refer to the absence of this phone as "elided-h". More specifically, the elision is caused by [lenition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenition) or weakening of the sound, so "lenited-h" would be a little more precise.

In some cases, a sound not represented in the orthographic form of a word can be heard when spoken aloud (e.g. the /p/ that is often heard in the pronunciation of "something"). In these cases—as with elision/lenition—the "articulated" sound is often referred to by the name of the process that causes it to occur. In the case of "something", the /p/ is the result of [excrescence (a type of epenthesis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis) and so would be called exrescent-p or epenthetic-p. But there aren't really terms for talking about why sounds are *not* omitted.

One other potentially relevant term here: when two different pronunciations are acceptable in the same speech community, as in your 'vehicle' example, it's called [free variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variation). But this is not just restricted to pairs where a particular sound is omitted or articulated in some varieties but not others. /tə'meto/~/tə'mato/ is another example of free variation in which the difference between the two varieties is in the quality of one of the vowel sounds.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that the opposite of a silent letter is a ghost letter.  A letter that is pronounced even though it's not in the word.  Examples would include the invisible;

- `/B/` Sometimes in Thespian
- `/CH/` in Culture
- `/W/` in words like One and Once
- `/N/` in Personal
- `/J/` in Modular
- `/R/` in Colonel
- `/SH/` in Action